# How would I do this navigation?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xhtml

I have the following navigation menu,  My question is how would I do this in Wordpress (code wise) due to each nav item having a different class.  This navigation is going to be placed in front-page.php.

**Code:**

```
<div id="nav"> 
            <div class="grid_4_home hoverable"> 
                <a href="index.html"><h3>Home <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
            </div> 

            <div class="grid_4 hoverable"> 
                <a href="expertise.html"><h3>My Expertise <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
            </div> 

            <div class="grid_4_about hoverable"> 
                <a href="about.html"><h3>About Us <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
            </div> 

            <div class="grid_4 hoverable"> 
                <a href="testimonials.html"><h3>Testimonials <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
            </div> 

            <div class="grid_4 hoverable"> 
                <a href="reports.html"><h3>Case Reports <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
            </div> 

            <div class="grid_4_last hoverable"> 
                <a href="contact.html"><h3>Contact Us <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
            </div> 
        </div> <!-- end of nav -->
```

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from copying and pasting that as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your code straight into front-page.php file located in your theme folder. do it either with php `echo` or close php with `?>` then insert your html and then reopen php with `<?php`

then edit style.css and put in it any additional css code you might need for your classes..